# dynamically populating fields in a formset

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

I have two models that looks like this:

```
class RouteBase(models.Model):
    base        =   models.ForeignKey("Base")
    route       =   models.ForeignKey("Route")
    sequence    =   models.IntegerField()

class Route(models.Model):
    bases       =   models.ManyToManyField("Base", through="RouteBase", blank=True)
    description =   models.TextField(blank=True)
    #and a few other attributes omitted for brevity
```

...then a modelform that looks like this:

```
class RouteBaseForm(ModelForm):
    base = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Base.objects.all(), widget=forms.TextInput)
    sequence = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)

    class Meta:
        model = RouteBase
```

As you can see, the sequence widget is hidden, as I want this field to be automatically handled by django. I want the user to have to just enter the Base via a text box. The sequence is inferred by the order of the textboxes.

I have created a formset with this form for creating/editing all the bases in the route:

```
RouteBaseFormset = inlineformset_factory(Route, RouteBase, form=RouteBaseForm, extra=5, )
```

When this formset is created, the sequence field is empty. I need to fill it in with values before I save the formset (else it won't validate). I can think of about 4 ways to go about this

1. Right before I send the formset off to the template, I run this code:

```
    i=1
    for form in formset.forms:
        form.fields["sequence"].initial = i
        i += 1
```

This works fine, except for one problem. When the formset gets submitted back to the view for saving, **all** 5 extra fields that have been created with the formset are filled in with a sequence value. This causes problems when the user only wants to add 2 or 3 bases to the route. Validation errors popup because the required field "base" is empty for that form. I *could* run a bit of code after the formset has been POSTed that checks to see if a base is present, if not, remove the sequence, but if I'm going to do that, I may as well...

2. Run a bit of code when the formset is POSTed that checks to see if a Base has been entered, if so, add a sequence, if not, then leave that field blank. That way when you try to `.save()` the formset, the empty values ensure that that particular form is not put into the database. The only problem is that I can't do anything to the form until I run `.save(commit=False)` which I can't do because the formset doesn't validate. But I could...
3. Add the sequence values by copying the `request.POST` variable and manually setting the sequence, but that seems awfully hacky.
4. I could also just remove `blank=True` from one of my `RouteBase` fields, but I don't really want to do that.

So what should I do here?

Answer (score 5):

If you never intend to have a user edit the sequence field and plan on always calculating it's value on the back end, you can [exclude it from the form](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form), rather than having it hidden.

Then you can use commit=False and handle the calculation of your sequence field as needed.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working. It doesn't matter what fields I exclude, if there is no sequence, the form won't validate, and therefore won't `.save(commit=False)`

Comment: You'll need to set blank=True in your model for that field. Since you are responsible for generating that value yourself (not the user) you don't need form validation for it.

Answer (score -2):

```
newPOST = request.POST.copy()
i=1
for index in range(0, int(request.POST["routebase_set-TOTAL_FORMS"])-1):
    if request.POST["routebase_set-" + str(index) + "-base"]:
        newPOST["routebase_set-" + str(index) + "-sequence"] = i
        i += 1
    else:
        newPOST["routebase_set-" + str(index) + "-sequence"] = ""
```

Honestly, this seems to work better than any messing around with form validation. It's not as hacky as I thought it be either...

Comment: -1 this is quite ugly.  The form validation approach is much simpler and cleaner.